# Reduzir as fontes ou quebrar texto em Bootstrap 4 ou HTML5

Tags: php, html5, css3, bootstrap-4

Os nomes das pessoas em meu HTML, quando responsivo, tem uma quebra, como mostra a imagem a seguir:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O nome Sanderson, o "N" vai pra baixo, tem como não ter esta quebra ou diminuir a fonte?

Segue o trecho em HTML:

```
</section>
    <section class="engine"></section>
    <section class="testimonials5 cid-qTbDs8s2OT" id="testimonials5-j">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="media-container-row">
                <div class="title col-12 align-center">
                    <h3 class="mbr-section-subtitle mbr-light pb-3 mbr-fonts-style display-5">

                    </h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="media-container-column">
                <div class="mbr-testimonial align-center col-12 col-md-10">
                    <div class="panel-item">
                        <div class="card-block">
                        <div class="testimonial-photo">
                            <?php 
                            echo '
                                <img src="cadastros/cadastros/_lib/file/imgimg_candidato/'.$resultado[0]['foto_padrao_tse'].'">                                
                            '; ?>
                        </div>                       
                        <div class="card-footer">
                            <?php echo '
                            <p class="mbr-text mbr-fonts-style mbr-white display-2"><strong>'.$resultado[0]['nome_politico'].'
                            </strong></p>

                            <div class="mbr-author-name mbr-bold mbr-fonts-style mbr-white display-5">
                            '.$resultado[0]['cargo_politico'].'</div> 
                            <small class="mbr-author-desc mbr-italic mbr-light mbr-fonts-style mbr-white display-7"><strong>
                            '.$resultado[0]['estado'].'<br>'.$resultado[0]['partido'].'</strong><br><br><br></small>'; ?>

                            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="https://www.site.com.br/restrito.php?id_candidato=<?php echo $_SESSION['id_candidato']; ?>">

                                  DOAR PARA SEU PRÉ-CANDIDATO</a>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para manter as palavrar inteiras mesmo sendo maior que a div que estão dentro vc pode usar `word-break: keep-all` Veja no exemplo como fica.

```css
div {
    width: 60px;
    word-break: keep-all;
    border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <p>
        Paralelepípedo Paralelepípedo
    </p> 
</div>
```

Existem duas formas de controlar a quebra de palavras dentro de uma `div` por exemplo. Uma com **`word-wrap:break-word`** outra com **`word-break: break-all`** O primeiro joga a palavra para uma nova linha que acredito ser o que vc quer. Já o segundo a palavra continua na mesma linha e só quebra para baixo quando atinge a borda da `div`.

Veja no exemplo como é o comportamento de cada um.

```css
.box{
    width:350px;
    height:100px;
    background-color: #4682B4;
    border-radius: 10px;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
    }

.impo2 { font-family: arial; color: white; }

.ult2{
    color: white; 
    font-family: Verdana; 
    font-size: large; 
}

.bw{
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
.ba{
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<div class="box bw"><center><a class="ult2"><br>Servidores com maiores erros: </a><a class="impo2">Paralelepípedo Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum, odit?</a></center></div>

    <div class="box ba"><center><a class="ult2"><br>Servidores com maiores erros: </a><a class="impo2">Paralelepípedo Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum, odit?</a></center></div>
```

---

**Tag `<wbr>`**

Ainda exite a opção de usar a tag `<wbr>` que serve para indicar ao browser onde ele deve quebrar uma palava. Vc pode ler mais sobre essa tag aqui https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/wbr

Exemplo prático:

```css
div {
    width: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <p>
       Paralele<wbr>pípedo
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Deu certo aqui. Obrigado! :)